# Android blurring dynamic / scrolling content

Tags: java, android, blur, renderscript

I need help implementing a blurring solution in order to accomplish the following :

1. I have a ScrollView matching the whole activity, with a dynamic content : content can be added, animated, deleted etc. ;
2. I have a header that *hides* the content as it gets scrolled away by the top of the screen

That **header** is in fact the one supposed to blur the content that passes under and then disappear out of the screen.

I tried using many libraries such as [Stackblur](https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur), [paveldudka's blurring](https://github.com/paveldudka/blurring) and lastly [500px own library](https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur).

Some of them failed (either no blur, or not the expected result) and I still trying to find out why...
All of them use the same technology `Android RenderScript Library`.

The main issue there is that these libraries provide a one-time rendering. Meaning, their blur once and that's it. It's perfect for fixed background / content.

500px library is the closest to what I am looking for :

1. their demo presents a screen with animated images and a blurring square in the middle ;
2. if said images passes under said blurring square, they get blurred, **dynamically**

Looking at the code, the blurring is re-rendered in an **update method** from the animation listener. This is very costly and I wonder if it is the way to go.

Comment: there is probably no efficient enough way to dynamically blur the ui during animation like scrolling. and when I say 'efficient', I mean performance wise.

Anyways, try this lib: https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

Comment: Thank you but it would seem that this library is a an easy-to-use solution to blur images. Once again, perfect for fixed content. No way to use it in a ScrollView. As you are saying, I believe their is no such way to accomplish what I am looking for. I would need to have bitmapdrawable drawn out of a rectangle the size of the header that captures the content below the header, blur it and set it to the header background. And in my case I'd have to do this each time the user scrolls...

Comment: another option is to mimic the feeling of a blur image, something with semi transparent layers. If your view that has to blurred looks pretty similar in term of colors, you can produce one blurred image and use a semi transparent layer of that.

Comment: @gilgil28 I agree with your option. I was thinking about the same. Something transparent with gradient colors. The problem is the scrolling content can be quite diverse so the rendering will not be quite satisfactory. But that's still a viable option. Thank you for your input :) what is very strange though, is that on iOS it's very easy to do that :/

Comment: maybe it's worthy to check how this is implemented in iOS.
It must be some kind of a workaround, probably more sofisticated than what I suggested

Answer (score 0):

in case you havn't found any sufficient solution, I am adding how I blur my entire screen, this is supposed to be the fastest most efficient way to do it with RS:

```
private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.05f;
private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 8.0f;

    private Bitmap blurImage (Bitmap input) {
        if (input == null){
            return null;
        }

        int width = Math.round(input.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
        int height = Math.round(input.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

        Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(input, width, height, false);
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = null;

        theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

        return outputBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your great input but unfortunately I already tried very similar techniques on multiple occasion. Your solution is the right way to blur any content, but not on the fly as I am trying to do. Thanks anyway!